# undefined method `remote_function'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am using rails-3.2.1 with blacklight application

I am trying to invoke remote_function in my link_to tag.

```
<%= link_to_document document, :label=>document_show_link_field, :onclick =>     remote_function(:controller => 'catalog', :action => 'save_user_history') %>
```

This gives following error

```
undefined method `remote_function' for #<#<Class:0x2ff0dc0>:0x2f4af38>.
```

Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 5):

This function was part of the [Prototype helper](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v3.0.13/actionpack/lib/action_view/helpers/prototype_helper.rb) which was [removed from the framework with Rails 3.1](http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2011/4/21/jquery-new-default/) and moved to the [prototype-rails gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/prototype-rails).

Comment: Ok. I want to invoke the action save_user_history as an onclick event of the link. What else i can use here in place of remote_function?

Comment: Use button_to which doesn't require javascript.

Answer (score 2):

You can always use a normal link_to.

```
<%= link_to "Save User History", save_user_history_catalogs_path %>
```

Or if it is a ajax function, something like this:

```
<a id="save_user_history">Save User History</a>
```

And in your javascript file:

```
$("#save_user_history").click(function() {
  $.post("/catalogs/save_user_history", function(data) {
    ....
```

Comment: In my application, i have list of links, each of which redirect to some webpage. I want to store the URLs of the visited links in my database, which i am trying to do with javascript onclick event, but i am not able to invoke the required ruby method.